# HTML 5 Video tag not showing fullscreen button

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I am trying to get a video with the video tag to include a fullscreen option in the controls. If I insert a video into a site using the following:

```
<video controls>
    <source src="filename.mp4 " type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I do not get the full screen button.

[image]

Interestingly when you look at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) the example on the page shows the fullscreen but when you click the **Try me** it does not.

[image]

Could it be because the tag is inside an frame? Is there a way around this?

Comment: Show a link to your demo page of such issue and mention what's your browser. Could not recreate issue, even the W3Schools "Try me" video has fullscreen button available. Tested on Chrome only.

Comment: Interestingly it is fine in Chrome and IE. Fine also in Firefox when not in a frame. Try the W3 example in Firefox and see if it misbehaves for you.

Comment: Unless I missed the memo, there is no fullscreen property in `<video>`. What you are seeing is from the web page they are using as an example.

Comment: @rob When I view the W3 page as per the link it shows the full screen (left image). When I click on the Try Me the full screen button has gone (right image). I assume because it is in a frame. I have the same issue on my site when viewed in Firefox and this is the problem.

Comment: @RGriffiths I tried it in Firefox and see what you mean now. It's not obvious from the `<video>` tag code you posted that your video is being viewed via some `<iframe>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"Could it be because the tag is inside an frame? Is there a way around this?"*

Yes that seems to be the cause after some investigation. Putting a `<video>` tag inside an `<iframe>` will cause the fullscreen button to disappear in Firefox.

Regarding W3Schools...

- The first page creates an actual video tag (see line **1143** of source code).
- On the second "*Try it yourself*" page they're actually creating an iframe (see line **541** of "*Try it*" page's source code): `var ifr = document.createElement("iframe");` etc.

**Solution**:
In the iframe code, add `allowfullscreen`, `webkitallowfullscreen`and `mozallowfullscreen`.

If using an `<iframe>` to load another HTML page (which holds the shown `<video>` code) then try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe width="800" height="600" src="video_page.html" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen> </iframe>

</body>
```

PS:

> *"If I insert a video into a site using the following... [see posted code]"*

Your posted code works fine. A `<video>` tag in a web page should have fullscreen controls. The problem you describe only shows up when using `<iframe>`.