# How to enable fullscreen button in video-tag HTML in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, fullscreen

I have a HTML script on my webpage with a video-tag, like this:

```
<video width="640" height="480" controls 
src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

In Firefox this turns out like this, with the possibility to go into fullscreen:
[image]

But in Chrome it shows up like this, and I cannot press the fullscreen button:
[image]

How can I get the possibility of going into fullscreen in Chrome?
I'm using Chrome version 104.0.5112.81

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML 5 Video tag not showing fullscreen button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59865813/html-5-video-tag-not-showing-fullscreen-button)

Comment: Try setting up your [video tag code like this code example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video) (no need for the `.ogg` file part). Likely issues are: You did not close `>` the video tag after `controls` and you don't set a `<source>` tag. If still failing then show a link to a page of problem in action.

Comment: This is the page where it's not working: https://diver.mestergruppen.no/diveport#page=5778b04d-ed89-44cf-9c89-95b76a73c0d4

Answer (score -2):

I was having the same problem. I found a solution to the problem. You should add 'allowfullscreen' to the video tag.

I am using it as an iframe. If you use it as follows, the fullscreen button becomes active.

```
<iframe src="video.mp4" id="video" allowscriptaccess="always" allow="autoplay" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I hope it will be useful for you.